# C++ multithreading - condition variable supplying data in a wrong way

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, mutex, condition-variable

I've got this multithreading project where I'm supposed to create a simulation of a hotel.

I've got this receptionist struct and their job is to constantly find if there's a free room (done in `check_free_rooms` method, `accommodate_guests` is his thread method). If he found a `number_to_check_in`, `is_a_room_ready` is set to `true` and one of guest threads waiting for a room is notified.

Every guest has a field which is a reference to the receptionist (there is only one in the hotel) and the guests are waiting on the receptionist's condition variable `receptionist.cv` to be notified with the condition of `receptionist.is_a_room_ready` becoming true. Then, if I understand correctly, one random guest should get a room and the other ones should patiently wait for another notification from the receptionist.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <chrono>
#include <algorithm>
#include <experimental/random>
#include <atomic>
#include <ncurses.h>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <memory>

std::mutex mx_writing;

struct Guest;

struct Room
{
    Room() {}
    int id;
    int guest_id;
    std::atomic<bool> is_ready_for_guest{true};

    void guest_arrives(int guest_id)
    {
        this->guest_id = guest_id;
        this->is_ready_for_guest = false;
    }
    void guest_leaves(int guest_id)
    {
        this->guest_id = -1;
    }
};

struct Receptionist
{
    Receptionist(std::vector<Room> &rooms) : rooms(rooms) {}
    std::vector<Room> &rooms;

    std::mutex mx;
    std::condition_variable cv;
    std::atomic<bool> is_a_room_ready{false};
    int number_to_check_in = 0;

    void check_free_rooms()
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock_receptionist(mx);
        do
        {
            this->number_to_check_in = std::experimental::randint(0, (int)rooms.size() - 1); //find an empty room
        } while (!rooms[this->number_to_check_in].is_ready_for_guest);
        is_a_room_ready = true;
        cv.notify_one();
    }

    void accommodate_guests()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            check_free_rooms();
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(100));
        }
    }
};

struct Guest
{
    Guest(int id, Receptionist &receptionist, Coffee_machine &coffee_machine,
          Swimming_pool &swimming_pool) : id(id), receptionist(receptionist),
                                          coffee_machine(coffee_machine), swimming_pool(swimming_pool) {}
    int id;
    int room_id;

    Receptionist &receptionist;
    Coffee_machine &coffee_machine;
    Swimming_pool &swimming_pool;

    void check_in()
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock_receptionist(receptionist.mx);
        while (!receptionist.is_a_room_ready)
        {
            receptionist.cv.wait(lock_receptionist);
        }
        receptionist.is_a_room_ready = false;
        this->room_id = receptionist.number_to_check_in;           //assign room to guest
        receptionist.rooms[this->room_id].guest_arrives(this->id); //assign guest to room && room becomes occupied
        {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> writing_lock(mx_writing);
            std::cout << "Guest " << this->id << " accomodated in room " << this->room_id << std::endl;
        }
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(20));
    }

    void have_holiday()
    {
        check_in();
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(std::experimental::randint(500, 700)));
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<Room> rooms(10);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        rooms[i].id = i;
    }

    Receptionist receptionist(rooms);

    std::vector<Guest> guests;
    for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
    {
        guests.emplace_back(Guest(i, receptionist, coffee_machine, swimming_pool));
    }

    std::vector<std::thread> threadList;

    threadList.emplace_back(std::thread(&Receptionist::accommodate_guests, std::ref(receptionist)));
    for (Guest guest : guests)
    {
        threadList.emplace_back(std::thread(&Guest::have_holiday, std::ref(guest)));
    }

    for (std::thread &t : threadList)
    {
        t.join();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

However, the lines that appear in the terminal after a guest gets their room are not quite what I imagined. Guest ids range from 0 to 14 and room ids range from 0 to 9 but only rooms seem to be more or less ok in the outputs. I've got no idea why guest ids are a random large int and not the ones I assigned while object construction.

I'm not that very experienced with multithreading and condition variables and have virtually no clue how to solve this problem as I gave it a lot of thinking and came up with nothing. I'd very much appreciate any help.

Some example outputs:

```
Guest 5 accommodated in room 32657
Guest -624431120 accommodated in room 7
Guest -624431120 accommodated in room 9
Guest -624431120 accommodated in room 8
Guest -624431120 accommodated in room 5
Guest -624431120 accommodated in room 4
Guest -624431120 accommodated in room 3
Guest -624431120 accommodated in room 2
Guest -624431120 accommodated in room 0
Guest -624431120 accommodated in room 6
^C
```

or

```
Guest 4 accommodated in room 32539
Guest -497561616 accommodated in room 1
Guest -497561616 accommodated in room 9
Guest -497561616 accommodated in room 5
Guest -497561616 accommodated in room 8
Guest -497561616 accommodated in room 6
Guest -497561616 accommodated in room 7
Guest -497561616 accommodated in room 3
Guest -497561616 accommodated in room 4
Guest -497561616 accommodated in room 0
^C
```

or

```
Guest 4 accommodated in room 32746
Guest -1510756368 accommodated in room 8
Guest -1510756368 accommodated in room 1
Guest -1510756368 accommodated in room 7
Guest -1510756368 accommodated in room 4
Guest -1510756368 accommodated in room 2
Guest -1510756368 accommodated in room 5
Guest -1510756368 accommodated in room 9
Guest -1510756368 accommodated in room 6
Guest -1510756368 accommodated in room 3
^C
```

Comment: Where is `mx_writing` defined?

Comment: `for (Guest guest : guests)` you are making a copy of guest here, and taking a reference to it?

Comment: @KorelK Globally, I edited the question

Comment: @cigien Do you mean this way of iterating over `guests` could be the problem?

Comment: Yes, try `for (Guest &guest : guests)` and see what happens.

Comment: @cigien Seems to have worked like a charm, thanks a lot for spotting this! But could you explain a bit more what difference the ampersand made?

Comment: The `&` means `guest` is a reference to every element in `guests`. This is *usually* what you want, so prefer this syntax. In fact, do `for (Guest const &guest : guests)` when you don't want to change the elements at all.

Comment: @cigien I used to think that the version I used iterates over the original objects, not copies, thank you for clarifying that for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace:

```
for (Guest guest : guests) {
    threadList.emplace_back(std::thread(&Guest::have_holiday, std::ref(guest)));
}
```

With:

```
for (Guest &guest : guests) {
    threadList.emplace_back(std::thread(&Guest::have_holiday, std::ref(guest)));
}
```

In your code, you are creating a copy of guest in every iteration instead of using the existing one.
Pay attention to `Guest guest` [copy] vs `Guest &guest` [reference].
[Read about references in C++](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/references-in-c/).

**Another Fix:**

```
for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
    guests.emplace_back(Guest(i, receptionist, coffee_machine, swimming_pool));
}
```

In this section, you are creating the guest object twice in each iteration. In `emplace_back` you can just pass the parameters for the constructor without creating a copy:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
    guests.emplace_back(i, receptionist, coffee_machine, swimming_pool);
}
```

Comment: Could you explain why the second snippet is not making a copy?

Comment: Much better, thanks. Note that another fix is not really a "fix", but perhaps an "improvement".

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation (also provided by @cigien) and for another improvement suggestion.

Comment: @Theta no problem. About the improvement suggestion, pay attention that it holds also for `threadList.emplace_back(&Receptionist::accommodate_guests, std::ref(receptionist));` and for `threadList.emplace_back(&Guest::have_holiday, std::ref(guest));`.